# R Error: Possible "misspecification" of input ranges resulting in missing values?

Tags: r, function, loops, optimization

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to use the following library (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mopsocd/mopsocd.pdf) for the optimizing a function with constraints.

First, I loaded the library:

```
#Load library:
library(mopsocd)
```

Then, I created some data for this example:

```
#load libraries
library(dplyr)


# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)
```

I then defined the function used in this example:

```
#define function:

funct_set <- function (x) {
    
    
    
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>%
        mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= x[1] & b1 <= x[3], "a",
                            ifelse(a1 <= x[2] & b1 <= x[4], "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    
    
    #calculate  quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = ifelse(c1 > x[5],1,0 )))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = ifelse(c1 > x[6],1,0 )))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = ifelse(c1 > x[7],1,0 )))
    
    f1 = mean(table_a$quant)
    f2 = mean(table_b$quant)
    f3 = mean(table_c$quant)
    
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
    # calculate the total mean : this is what needs to be optimized
    
    f4 = mean(final_table$quant)
    
    
    return (c(f1, f2, f3, f4));
}
```

Then, I defined the constraints :

```
#define constraints

gn <- function(x) {
    g1 <- x[3] - x[1] >= 0.0
    g2 <- x[4] - x[2] >= 0.0
    g3 <- x[7] - x[6] >0
    g4<- x[6] - x[5] >0
    return(c(g1,g2,g3, g4))
}
```

Next, I customized some of the options for the optimization function (e.g. number of variables, lower and upper bounds for the ranges, etc.)

```
## Set Arguments

varcount <- 7
fncount <- 4
lbound <- c(80,85,100,120,90, 110, 130)
ubound <- c(220,220,220,220,220, 145, 189)
optmin <- 0
```

Lastly, I ran the optimization function itself:

```
#run optimization



ex1 <- mopsocd(funct_set,gn, varcnt=varcount,fncnt=fncount,
                lowerbound=lbound,upperbound=ubound,opt=optmin)
```

**Problem:** However, this produces the following error:

```
Error in if ((max(rowSums(x)) == fncnt) == FALSE) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Does anyone know why this error is being produced? Is it because I have used an incorrect format to define the functions? Is it because the ranges (e.g. "lbound" and "ubound") are illogical?

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You've missed some code out in your copying. For example, it looks like you should be loading `library(tidyverse)` and you've misspelled `mopsocd` in your first line of code. You also seem to have not included your `train_data` (or any suitable substitute) in the question. Anyway, as a guess, try setting `na.rm = TRUE` as an argument to your `max` function.

Comment: @ J. Mini: thank you for your suggestions! I fixed the typo and added the "train_data"

Comment: Why are you grouping by `cat` after filtering your data such that the data that you're trying to group only has one value of `cat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error indicates that missing values have got in to your process somewhere. Stepping in to your final function call `ex1 <- mopsocd(...)` and running it until just before the error reveals several internal variables with `NaN` values. Stepping carefully through this last call from the very start, we see that the missing values first appear roughly when the internal variable `popFit` is generated. This is a table with four columns, one for each of your `f`s. This suggests that the error is that one of your `f`s is a cause of missing values. A visual inspection has me blame `f2` and `f3`.

Setting a new breakpoint at `f4` and checking it every now and then when running your code (really, try this yourself - it's revealing) shows us that your `b_table` and `c_table` are often empty. In plain English, the cause of your error is that there are frequently no values in either category b or c.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This is something I have been struggling with a lot. If you have time, can you please check out this question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324822/correctly-specifying-logical-conditions-in-r ? I think I was able to come up with an answer, but I am not sure if I have done it correctly. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @stats555 Your definition of the constraints seems faithful to the example code given by the library and your outputs seem to satisfy said constraints. I see no cause for concern.